# Wacom tablet detected, but not the stylus

Tags: 18.04, tablet, wacom

I'm trying to get my Wacom Intuos Pen and Touch device working. The tablet itself seems to be detected, and I can move the mouse pointer with my finger, but the stylus seems to be entirely missing in all settings. From what I understand, there should be 4 devices: pad, touch, stylus and eraser

Here's the output of various things I've tried to diagnose the problem. The only thing that looks awry is the 'can't add hid device: -71', but I don't know what do do from there.

```
$ udev

[  723.354522] usb 5-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  723.483962] usb 5-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=0302
[  723.483964] usb 5-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  723.483966] usb 5-1.2: Product: Intuos PTS
[  723.483967] usb 5-1.2: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[  723.503608] usbhid 5-1.2:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[  723.503623] usbhid: probe of 5-1.2:1.0 failed with error -71
[  723.508224] input: Wacom Intuos PT S Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1.2/5-1.2:1.1/0003:056A:0302.0012/input/input33
[  723.508344] input: Wacom Intuos PT S Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1.2/5-1.2:1.1/0003:056A:0302.0012/input/input34
[  723.508471] wacom 0003:056A:0302.0012: hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PTS] on usb-0000:09:00.3-1.2/input1

$ xsetwacom list devices
Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch      id: 10  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad           id: 11  type: PAD  

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$ libwacom-list-local-devices 

# Device node: /dev/input/event7
[Device]
Name=Intuos Pen & Touch Small
ModelName=CTH-480
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:0302;
Class=Bamboo
Width=6
Height=4
IntegratedIn=
Layout=intuos-s-pt.svg
Styli=0xffffe;0xfffff;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=true
TouchSwitch=true
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=4

[Buttons]
# Left=
# Right=
Top=A;B;C;D;
# Bottom=
# Touchstrip=
# Touchstrip2=
# OLEDs=
# Ring=
# Ring2=
EvdevCodes=0x110;0x111;0x115;0x116;
RingNumModes=0
Ring2NumModes=0
StripsNumModes=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
# Device node: /dev/input/event6
[Device]
Name=Intuos Pen & Touch Small
ModelName=CTH-480
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:0302;
Class=Bamboo
Width=6
Height=4
IntegratedIn=
Layout=intuos-s-pt.svg
Styli=0xffffe;0xfffff;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=true
TouchSwitch=true
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=4

[Buttons]
# Left=
# Right=
Top=A;B;C;D;
# Bottom=
# Touchstrip=
# Touchstrip2=
# OLEDs=
# Ring=
# Ring2=
EvdevCodes=0x110;0x111;0x115;0x116;
RingNumModes=0
Ring2NumModes=0
StripsNumModes=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd have a crack and enabling, or disabling ID 10 or 11 with     xinput enable <ID#>

Answer (score 2):

So I don't know exactly what the problem is, but switching to a different USB port seems to fix it. The original USB port still doesn't work, or the one next to it, but I found a port that works.

Comment: Reconnecting on another port works and preferably on a usb 3 port.